# swift optimize http post request

Tags: ios, mysql, swift

i have this code to make an http post request to my mysql database:

```
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "https://xxxxx")!)
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
let postString = "email=\(txtEmail.text!)&password=\(txtPassword.text)"

request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
    data, response, error in

    // if no internet connection
    guard error == nil && data != nil else {
       print("error=\(error)")
       return
    }

let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
  if responseString.isEqualToString("OK") { 
       self.performSegueWithIdentifier("GoToMain", sender: nil)
  } else {
       self.performSegueWithIdentifier("GoBack", sender: nil)   
  }

});
}
task.resume()
```

In this database are a the moment round about 5500 entries.
the answer (responseString) came after 3 - 4 seconds.
my opinion is, that this is to long.

is there an way to make the request quicker?
for example only 2 seconds?

Comment: 1. Query DB specifying "limit" 
2. Implement web service that give you a paged response 
In each cases, you should do a page request, for instance retrieving 100 rows by time.

Comment: what do you mean with limit? and what do you mean with web service an page request? at the moment, my post request call an php file which makes an sql request like: `SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE EMAIL = EMAIL AND PASSWORD = PASSWORD`(only a simple example)

Comment: 1) I mean "select * ..... where ... limit 100" || 2) My fault, you're already using your webservice. So, in the post body you can specify the limit and do the pagination job. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13009364/on-request-paginationpaginate-records-on-demand-of-user for example

Comment: okay, but for what i should use the pagination. my sql request give always only one row as result. and i have set an limit in my request: `SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE EMAIL = EMAIL AND PASSWORD = PASSWORD LIMIT 1`